# Selecting a proportion mix from three respondent groups?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, predictive-models, prediction, sample

Let's say you have a system to ask random people a polling question with an offer to buy something at the end of the poll. So your respondents fall into one of three categories

1. Refused to answer at all
2. Provided an answer or two but didn't buy anything
3. Provided answers and also bought something at the end

I want to create a predictive model to better find respondents that would buy something at the end of the poll (group 3 from above). The initial respondents are chosen at random, so I don't have much demographic data. But I do have the ability to collect the demographic data after the poll question, from third-party sources.

For predictive modeling, and collecting the demographic data for cross-validation testing, what proportion mix of people would you pick from the above? Would you just collect equal amounts of respondents from each group? Would you only collect data from group 3 for unsupervised learning?

Comment: It might be easier if you treated this as a binary classification problem and not tertiary. In any case it, if you are doing classification it is useful to have plenty of information about each class and that means plenty of data about each class.

Comment: @MeadowlarkBradsher understood and that is a good point. But are you ultimately suggesting an equal mix from each group? I guess I'm mostly concerned about the overall proportion (spread over the three groups) more than anything else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a random sample of people, how can you choose how many from each group?  But maybe you want to estimate a model from this sample (and retrospectively obtained demographic data), to use in future ... Maybe in future you really want to find the people in group 3.

Then I would try [multinomial logistic regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=multin*+logist*+regr*+answers%3A1+score%3A3..).  Then you would have a starting point. As an alternative, two binary logistic regression models, the first for 1) versus 2&3), the second for 2 versus 3, given they answered.